# problemas de cortes de control en c++

Tags: c++

> En una biblioteca pública, se prestan ejemplares de los libros que allí se
> encuentran. El encargado de la biblioteca desea saber de que género fueron los libros solicitados con más frecuencia, que autor dentro de cada género, es el más solicitado por el público y cantidad de libros por género.
>
> Los datos vienen ordenados por código de género y dentro de cada género ordenados por código de autor, y son los siguientes:
>
> - Código de género: un numero entero entre 1y 10
> - Código de autor: un número entre 1 y 100
> - Nombre del autor
> - Código del libro
> - Título del libro

Ya hice algo como esto:

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        float total_codigog=0, codigo_g, codigo_ant, codigo_a,total_codigoa=0,codigo_l=0;
        string nautor, titulo_l;
        int cant=0;
        cout<<"ingrese codigo de genero"<<endl;
        cin>>codigo_g;
        while (codigo_g!=0){
                total_codigog=0;
                total_codigoa=0;
                codigo_ant=codigo_g;
                //mientras el codigo del genero sea iagual al codigo anterior
            while(codigo_g==codigo_ant){
               cout<<"ingrese codigo de autor"<<endl;
               cin>>codigo_a;
               total_codigoa+=codigo_a;
               cout<<"ingrese nombre del autor"<<endl;
               cin>>nautor;
               cout<<"ingrese codigo de libro"<<endl;
               cin>>codigo_l;
               cout<<"ingrese titulo del libro"<<endl;
               cin>>titulo_l;
            cout<<"ingrese codigo de genero"<<endl;
            cin>>codigo_g;
            }
```

En estas parte más o menos es en la que me perdí que esto básicamente es para mostrar los resultados

```
            for(){
    
            for(){
               if(codigo_g=codigo_ant){
            total_codigog++;
                 cant=cant+codigo_l;
                 nautor=codigo_a;
            //en totalcodigog se ingremeta
           }
            }
            }
    
        }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: no deja ya encontre el problema